# Compiled C# exe how to use with Robot Framework?

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing, robotframework, user-acceptance-testing

I have a compiled C# executable. It basically opens Microsoft Word and creates a Word Document saves it and closes it. (I used .Net to create it.)

Now I would like to have Robot Framework to run tests based from this compiled C# exe.

I have found this example:
https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/HowToUseCSharp

Unfortunately, this example uses a dll as an example.
Does anyone know if there is an example that uses an exe.

I am basically looking for more ways to integrate C# and Robot Framework.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a exe exactly the same way you use a DLL, just include the exe as a reference just as you would a .net DLL and everything else should be exactly the same.

(Note: If you where working with Native instead of managed code like C++, this would not work! .NET treats .DLL assemblies and .EXE assemblies exactly the same, it is just one will start a `static void Main(` function if you double click it in windows)